# Does getting tons of levels waste XP?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I have 200 levels and enchant something, does it take 3 levels like enchanting at 30 levels does? I ask this because it gets really hard to get more levels the higher you get and getting high levels seems like a waste.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Gaming.SE! Glad to see you! Have you tried to research the issue before asking here? Questions that show research effort tend to be accepted better than those that don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of what your current XP levels are, it will only take 1, 2 or 3 levels of experience, depending on which tier your choose.

The requirement however, is that you have at least 30 levels in order to enchant at tier 3. So, the benefit is that you can enchant many many times, for example, if you have 200 levels.

In regard to the math, however, yes, technically it is a "waste". The [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Experience) states that getting from level 39 to level 40 requires almost double what it requires to go from 29 to 30.

That said, not only is experience unlimited, it has several uses - enchanting, using an anvil (renaming, combining and repairing) and repairing equipment and armour with the Mending enchantment.

As for *why* it was made that way, that's up to the devs - only they can answer that.